# Tensorflow - ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (128,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_142:0', which has shape '(?, 3433)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

after several unsuccesfull tries, I would like to ask your help in solving this error.
I am trying to train a deep autoencoder network, by using a local csv file that is then transformed (by the csv and the numpy libraries) into a numpy array. But this data is never feeding into my placeholder's tensor.

Here's an abstract of the deep autoencoder:

```
class Deep_Autoencoder:
    def __init__(self, input_dim, n_nodes_hl = (32, 16, 1), epochs = 400, batch_size = 128, learning_rate = 0.02, n_examples = 10):

    # Hyperparameters
    self.input_dim = input_dim
    self.epochs = epochs
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate
    self.n_examples = n_examples

    # Input and target placeholders
    X = tf.placeholder('float', [None, self.input_dim])
    Y = tf.placeholder('float', [None, self.input_dim])
    ...

    self.X = X
    print("self.X : ", self.X)
    self.Y = Y
    print("self.Y : ", self.Y)
    ...

def train_neural_network(self, data, targets):

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range(self.epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            i = 0

            # Let's train it in batch-mode
            while i < len(data):
                start = i
                end = i + self.batch_size

                batch_x = np.array(data[start:end])
                print("type batch_x :", type(batch_x))
                print("len batch_x :", len(batch_x))
                batch_y = np.array(targets[start:end])
                print("type batch_y :", type(batch_y))
                print("len batch_y :", len(batch_y))

                hidden, _, c = sess.run([self.encoded, self.optimizer, self.cost], feed_dict={self.X: batch_x, self.Y: batch_y})
                epoch_loss +=c
                i += self.batch_size

        self.saver.save(sess, 'selfautoencoder.ckpt')
        print('Accuracy', self.accuracy.eval({self.X: data, self.Y: targets}))
```

Here I create the input data and below you can see that I'll printout their main features for your info (note that I am actually interested on column 3 only):

```
features_DeepAE = create_feature_sets(filename)

Train_x = np.array(features_DeepAE[0])
Train_y = np.array(features_DeepAE[1])

print("type Train_x : ", type(Train_x))
print("type Train_x.T[3] : ", type(Train_x.T[3]))
print("len Train_x : ", len(Train_x))
print("len Train_x.T[3] : ", len(Train_x.T[3]))
print("shape Train_x : ", Train_x.shape)
print("type Train_y : ", type(Train_y))
print("type Train_y.T[3] : ", type(Train_y.T[3]))
print("len Train_y : ", len(Train_y))
print("len Train_y.T[3] : ", len(Train_y.T[3]))
print("shape Train_y : ", Train_y.shape)
```

And here I run the code:

```
DAE = Deep_Autoencoder(input_dim = len(Train_x))
DAE.train_neural_network(Train_x.T[3], Train_y.T[3])
```

These are the printouts, fyi:

```
type Train_x :  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
type Train_x.T[3] :  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
len Train_x :  3433
len Train_x.T[3] :  3433
shape Train_x :  (3433, 5)
type Train_y :  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
type Train_y.T[3] :  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
len Train_y :  3433
len Train_y.T[3] :  3433
shape Train_y :  (3433, 5)
self.X :  Tensor("Placeholder_142:0", shape=(?, 3433), dtype=float32)
self.Y :  Tensor("Placeholder_143:0", shape=(?, 3433), dtype=float32)
type batch_x : <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
len batch_x : 128
type batch_y : <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
len batch_y : 128
```

And finally the error:

**ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (128,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_142:0', which has shape '(?, 3433)'**

and yes... I'm at placeholder # 143... that meas a lot of failures (reshaping the batch and/or the tensor, transposing one and/or the other, looking for workarounds on internet..) !
Do not hesitate to ask for more info if needed.

Comment: Could you print one of the batches to see it's shape?

Comment: Can you upload your code somewhere? If you do, I will try to run it.

Comment: maybe print `batch_x.shape`

Comment: From what I understand in your code, you are trying to encode-decode a single feature. Thus, change `input_dim=1` instead of setting it to the number of samples in your trainset. In addition, if this is the case, encoding-decoding a single feature doesn't make sense..

Comment: @Elliot Roberts. Thanks but you already can see the batch_x shape printout

Comment: @ amirbar. Thx, but doing so: ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (128,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_2:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'

Comment: @ finbarr: this code is not a secret, so please just suggest a repository.

Comment: Following @amirbar 's suggestion - set your input_dim to 1 and add a "dummy" dimension to your batch_x and batch_y to make them fit into the placeholder of shape [?, 1] like this: ```batch_x = np.array(data[start:end])[:, None]``` and  ```batch_y = np.array(targets[start:end])[:, None]```. The None adds an empty dimension to a Numpy array.

Comment: @ Avishkar Bhoopchand and amirbar : the workaround seems working super well ! I've still to check all the following steps but that seems to be te solution, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, thanks to Avishkar Bhoopchand and amirbar :

Set your input_dim to 1 and add a "dummy" dimension to your batch_x and batch_y to make them fit into the placeholder of shape [?, 1] like this: batch_x = np.array(data[start:end])[:, None] and batch_y = np.array(targets[start:end])[:, None]. 
The None adds an empty dimension to a Numpy array.